Pen and paper to learn basic algebra instead of using latex and spaced repetition flash cards?
I've started to learn basic algebra.
I've used spaced repetition (anki) to learn languages and anatomy to a certain satisfaction.
Now I want to memorize : The Set of natural numbers without Zero.
My printed book depicts it beautyfully as:
$ {N}^{*} \doteq {N}\setminus{0} = \{ 1;2;... \} $
I spent 3 hours translating that string to LaTex in order to export it as flash card.
Almost every single character (higher asterisk, backslash) had to be researched.
$ {N}^{*} \doteq {N}\setminus{0} = \{ 1;2;... \} $
At this moment I spent 99% on learning about LaTex and html, but mathematics.
I imagine people without a computer being miles ahead, yet somehow I'm having a hunch that I should stick with my setup.
On hone hand, I'm telling myself just get over this initial phase until you've setup all mathematical symbols. Then copy/paste/try/error each latex char in order to create new flash cards.
On the other hand, I might just be biased towards my technical background and maybe should just toss everyhing distracting me from the essence, which is to learn mathematics
At the very end, I hope someone can share their experience on weighing up pen and paper against Latex to learn mathematics.

This is off-topic.

TeX.SE would be a good place to get guidance on learning LaTeX. You could also check Math.SE's MathJax tutorial for an overview of the kind of markup commonly used here.

... and why exactly do you want it on a flash card when you have a book???

@Dominique I'm not sure I understand the question. I want to learn what e.g. N,P etc. stands for. By heart.

@jjk: Do you mean you can't learn it from the book because you borrowed it (like from the library), or what reason do you have to export information to a flash card?

Memorising letters has nothing to do with learning mathematics, and I have never heard of anyone learning mathematics through flash cards. I hope this is not some new crazy trend. To learn mathematics you want to learn techniques and solve problems. Your goal is not memorisation but understanding and problem solving proficiency. Latex is a tool for communicating mathematics, not for learning it.

@AlexB. I was hoping for a commentary such as yours. Memorisation of abbreviations is apparently required. E.g. One question of the book out of the first chapter Sets (shortened but literal): State in words, what Sets the abbreviations N,Z,Q,R...  describe. The book is officially recommended by the swiss government to enroll in the entrance examination for studying datascience.

@jjk I imagine that there will be not that much of that. You will know the definitions of these particular symbols in no time, by just seeing them enough, since they are pretty ubiquitous. Actually understanding a rigorous definition of the set of real numbers, for example, is a much more serious step.

What is anki ?... I haven't been introduced.

@JeanMarie Anki is a spaced repetition based flash card software

Once you've overcome the initial hurdle of learning basic Latex, making math cards in Anki will be much easier. Usually, you'll just have to google the specific character you want to use (for example, \epsilon for $\epsilon$).
Since most character names are intuitive, you'll know the most important ones by heart pretty quickly.
That being said, I highly suggest you only learn important formulas that you truly need to memorize with Anki (since that won't be too many cards, you can also do it quite easily with pen & paper). The most important aspect of learning math is active problem-solving and understanding.
By focusing on those points, you'll be able to avoid a lot of memorization, since many formulas seem obvious once you've understood why they work. Remembering definitions is also easier when you understand the intuitive meaning behind them and have worked with them in problem-solving.
P.S. ^ and _ don't require brackets when you only want to super/subscript 1 character.
